# Rails Personal Message Plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any good "Rails Personal Messaging plugins"? [Or should I roll my own?](http://www.novawave.net/public/rails_messaging_tutorial.html) This is the features I might need:

- Send/recieve personal messages
- Notification by email. (you got a new message)
- Maybe contacts (not important)

Best regards.
Asbjørn Morell

Answer (score 0):

One option: use [acts_as_messageable](http://www.philsergi.com/2007/10/actsasmessageable-plugin-released_04.html), and send the notification e-mail in the callback method `Message#on_deliver`.

Comment: hmmm acts_as_messageable seems outdated. I was looking for something a bit more modern. Link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [simple-private-messages](http://github.com/professionalnerd/simple-private-messages) (uses restful auth)?